# Local Maxima with no monotonic neighborhood

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

In undergraduate level calculus, we just learned about Rolle’s, Lagrange, and Fermat’s theorems.

We learned that a local maxima is a point (c), for which exists a delta such that every x in the c’s neighborhood (x-delta,x+delta) is smaller than c.

The professor said that contrast to all logical intuition, there exists a function in which there does not exist a monotonic neighborhood around either side of c.

But he did not give a clue of how to construct one.

Does anyone have any idea what function could have this unique property?

**edit: How would you answer this question if f(x) is continuous?

Thank you

Comment: [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function)

Comment: Hey (@Galc). How would you answer the question if f(x) must be continuous? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One example is $f(x)=   |x||\sin \frac{1}{x}|$ for $x \neq0$ and $f(0)=0$. Also notice that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$ so $f$ is continuous.

We observe that there is a sequence $\xi_n\rightarrow 0$ such that $f(\xi_n)=0$. Now, since $f$ is not always zero near the origin $f$ cannot possibly be monotonous in any left or right neighborhood of zero.

For an example where $0$ is a strict local min. we can take $f(x)=|x||\sin \frac{1}{x}|+x^2$. When $|\sin \frac{1}{x}|$ vanishes then $f(x)$ behaves as $x^2$, and when $|\sin \frac{1}{x}|$ is $1$ then $f(x)$ behaves as $|x|$ since $|x|>>x^2$, therefore $f$ has the desired property.

We can also take a look at the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D%7Cx%20sin(1%2Fx)%7C%2Bx%5E2,%20%20%20x%3D-.1%20to%20.1) of $f$ to be convinced.

[image]

Comment: This has value $0$ at $x=0,$ and is always nonnegative, but since it is zero on a sequence of $x \to 0,$ the function does not have a strict local minimum at $x=0.$ OP seems to want that feature, not just a "weak local min".

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for the comment, I had missed that. I could add $x^2$ to $f(x)$ to make to example work but I am not sure how to write down nicely

Comment: Since $f(x)\ge 0$ and you have added $x^2$ the sum will be strictly positive for any $x \neq 0.$ [I think that's all that is needed.]

Comment: @coffeemath I added $x^2$ because $x^2$ is of lower order compared to $|x|$. However if we had chosen $\sqrt{|x|}$ I don't think the result still holds. For instance see the graph of $f(x)=|x \sin (\frac{1}{x})|+\sqrt{x}$ in a small neighborhood of the origin https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f(x)%3D%7Cx+sin+(1%2Fx)%7C%2Bsqrt(%7Cx%7C),+x%3D-.00000001+to+.00000001

Comment: clark-- I see your point, using $\sqrt(|x|)$ as the add-on makes the result have a unique min at zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer the professor provided when we asked him about it.

He said he was thinking about the family of functions which are Always Continuous, Nowhere Differentiable.
And because if a function is monotonous it must be differentiable, this function is nowhere monotonous.

I think it's beautiful and worth sharing.

Hope you enjoy it as well.

A concrete example of this function is:

The Weirstrass Function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

It's function:
$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a^{n}\cos(b^{n}\pi x),$$

And it's graph:
[image: Weierstrass function]